# My bubble sort seems to be running too many times, or running backwards

Tags: java, sorting, logic, bubble-sort

I am creating a program that prints out all the permutations of a sequence in lexicographical order. One part of the algorithm to do this, requires me to sort out all numbers into Ascending order after the point of where a swap has occurred.

However, my bubble sort seems to be rearranging the wrong numbers, even though it arranges them fine in the first 8 or so runs in the loop. I think it has to do with how many times my loop needs to run, but I can't work out what?

Here is an example of where my sort does not work:

The sequence will be: 2-3-4-1 and it needs to be rearranged as: 2-3-1-4. So after 3 all the numbers need to be rearranged into ascending order. However the output is: 2-1-3-4. Meaning it is rearranging them all after the 2 and not the 1.

Here is my sort:

```
for(int i=newTrueIndex; i < l; i++)
           {
              for(int j=seenCount+1; j < l; j++)
              {
                 if(seq[j-1] > seq[j])
                 {
                    int temp4=seq[j-1];
                    seq[j-1] = seq[j];
                    seq[j] = temp4; 

                 }
              }

           }
```

At this point newTrueIndex =1 and seenCount = 1

and the numbers are all stored in seq.

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes about the code

- Are you required to use bubble sort? (is this a homework assignment). If not there is java.util.Arrays.sort() [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) which you can use:
  `java.util.Arrays.sort(seq,  newTrueIndex, l)`
- My #1 guess is that the value of `l` is not what you expect it to be.
- j should starting from seeonCount creates a potential point of failure in your code. `i` and `j` should iterate over the same range. If your range is starting at `newTrueIndex` then both variables should start at this value. Adding a second starting point (namely: seenCount) can create problem if the two starting point are not kept in sync.
- `j` is starting from `seenCount` that is: a value that represent quantity but is used as an index. a count is equivalent to an index only if indexing starts from 0.

Comment: Hey no it's not homework, but Bubble Sort is the only sort that I know. Do I have to import anything to use the java.util.Arrays.sort 

How do you use the java.util.Arrays, what should my code look like if I want it to only sort it from a certain point?

Comment: if you use the fully qualified name of the Arrays class then you do not need to import anything. you need to replace the entire block of code that you posted with this statement: `java.util.Arrays.sort(seq, newTrueIndex, l);`

Comment: It didn't seem to be working, as I need it to start after the position that is seenCount, so when i changed it seenCount I just got the same problem as last time.

Comment: @itlay I changed it to: java.util.Arrays.sort(seq, seenCount, l-1); and it works up until 3-2-4-1 now.

Comment: Can you print the value of `l` and the value of `seenCount` just before the sort() method is called?

Comment: I changed it to: java.util.Arrays.sort(seq, seenCount, l-2); and it seemed to get the whole program working. whereby it starts at 1234 and prints all the permutations in lexicographical order until 4321. However if the sequence is 3 numbers long then I have to change it to l-1 for some reason? and I can't even get it working with something 5 numbers long? 

If I print seenCount before, it will always equal where I need to start changing. e.g. if I need to start changing at 12(3)4, seen count will equal 3 as the array index starts at 0. and l will equal 4 in this case as its the length (cont)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=newTrueIndex; i < l; i++){
    for(int j=newTrueIndex; j < i; j++){
        if(seq[i] < seq[j]){
            int temp4 = seq[i];
            seq[i] = seq[j];
            seq[j] = temp4; 
        }
    }
}
```

This should help you sort in ascending order.